# Create Hyperlinks for Images

Tags: excel, vba

I want to create a hyperlink for each inserted image.

In this example, Column A represents the name of the color swatch while Column B has an image.

Example:
Column A 1001
Column B Inserted Image

Expected result:
Column A 1001
Column B Inserted Image
Column C 1001.jpg

[image]
The hyperlink would be on Column C.
When a user clicks on the hyperlink, it would open the image based on the color name.

Answer (score 0):

Try this out:

```
Sub insertlink()

' insertlink Macro


    ActiveSheet.Shapes.Range(Array("Picture 2")).Select
    arr = Selection.ShapeRange.Item(1).Hyperlink.Address
    
    ''the cell you want the formula in needs to be selected. it is set to put 
    ''the value of the cell two to columns left of it as the value.
    ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "=RC[-2]"
    ActiveCell.Select     ''use activeCell to make this relative.''            
        Selection.Hyperlinks.Add Anchor:=Selection, Address:=arr
        
End Sub
```

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. It give me a run error based on this piece of code     arr = Selection.ShapeRange.Item(1).Hyperlink.Address

Comment: That may be because the "Item(1)" part may not be the item number that it is referencing on your sheet. if the run error says it is out of bounds that is the reason you are getting the error. you may want to try changing the 1 to a different number.

Comment: Also make sure your image has a link when you run the code.